# Variable selection in MLlib spark scala

Tags: r, apache-spark, bigdata, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I have a question about MLlib in Spark.(with Scala)

I'm trying to understand how LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS and LogisticRegressionWithSGD work.
I usually use SAS or R to do logistic regressions but I now have to do it on Spark to be able to analyze Big Data.

How is the variable selection done?
Is there any try of different variable combinations in LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS  or LogisticRegressionWithSGD? 
Something like a test of significance of variable one by one? 
Or a correlation calculation with the variable of interest?

Because the model only returns weights and intercept...

How can I understand those Spark functions and compare to what I'm used to in SAS or R ?

Comment: I think these sort of questions are ripe for the vendor or at least crossvalidated.com, as they don't pertain programming.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm going to post it on CrossValidated.com

Comment: No need, the question will be migrated "automatically".